# Logging project name dynamically with log4j?

Tags: java, log4j, project

Is it possible to dynamically log the project name using property (like  **${project.name}** in the appender below)? I'm using log4j.xml configuration file.

If yes, where can I define such a property?

```xml
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="[${project.name}] %d{ISO8601} [%t] %-5p ..%c{3}.%M(%L)  - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

By doing this, I'll be able to use the same log4j.xml in all my project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to build all your projects with [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/index.html) and use [resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

(of course Ant can do this as well and probably any other build system as well, but in Maven it's a standard mechanism that is well-known)

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. I've added <name>ProjectName</name> and <filtering>true</filtering> to my pom.xml and it worked fine.

Comment: I have a question. I'm using Gradle to build my project and I have property filtering enabled and should have my properties mapped correctly. However it's still outputting an empty string. Does anyone know if Gradle has any quirks there or could take a look at my code?

Comment: @AreusAstarte if you have a question, please post it as a question, and you'll get answers